# NMinimize applied to a function which depends on a complicated code

Tags: mathematical-optimization

I have a complicated code which puts out one value, which I want to minimize. Instead of copy pasting my code I present here a much simpler code which produces the same error.

```
range[x_] := Range[1, x]
f2[x_, y_, z_] := 
 Sum[(Sin[x] Exp[z] ArcTan[y])^n, {n, 1, x}] Norm[range[x]]
```

Please do not change this code above in your answer since it's not the real code. If I evaluate `f2[x,y,z]` for some positive and real `x,y,z`, I get a number. Just as the code I use.

However, if I do this:

```
NMinimize[{f2[x, y, z], 4 <= x <= 15, 2 <= y <= 4, 4 <= z <= 9}, {x, 
  y, z}]
```

I get an error message:

> Range::range: Range specification in Range[1,x] does not have
>   appropriate bounds.

How can I change Nminimize, or do something to the function f2 (without changing the code which creates f2) such that NMinimize works?

Comment: You need to make `range` only evaluate for numerical values.  Try using `range[x_?NumericQ] := Range[1, x]`.

Comment: `f2` should have its argument for `x` constrained to being numeric, i.e., `f2[x_?NumericQ, y_, z_] := ...`. As pointed out in the error message, `f2` is calling `range` with a symbolic value for `x`

Comment: See https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/18393/what-are-the-most-common-pitfalls-awaiting-new-users/26037#26037 for more info